# Windows Phone 7 SaveContactTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible?
1. Select contact and to be sure the selected contact, what user asking for (what parameter I have to use?) Than, use SaveContactTask to update info? SaveContactTask does not has all info of contact. Will some info be lost when user will save contact?

Answer (score 0):

`Contacts` API in Windows Phone Mango is read-only. Thus you can't update info of existing contacts. By using `SaveContactTask` you'll always will create a new contact.